# Building my first game in XCODE 7(swift 2)-CGPOINTMAKE?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift2, xcode7

I want to build a game similar to snooker, and at the beginning I already have some problems. I want to build four walls first (that will be the size of the screen-self.frame), and the first one I made like this:

```
let ground = SKNode()
ground.position = CGPointMake ( 0, 0)
ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody( rectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width * 3, 1))
ground.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
self.addChild(ground)
```

However, I don't known how to manipulate the values of CGPointMake to do the left/right/up walls. I first imagined that the (0,0) point was the left down corner, but it seems to not be like that. Can someone please help me with this or just explain how this works? (since in https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPointMake they dont explain very much =/)

Comment: First of all, are sure you want to make each wall separate ? If that so, use method bodyWithEdgeFromPoint: toPoint: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:toPoint: Second, are you sure you want to make physics body which is three times wider than a scene? Also take a look at bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect: for creating your walls. I can make an example for you, but you have to be more specific about dimensions for each wall.

Comment: Whirlwind, no , i'm not sure about anything, since i'm really new in programming! =p Thanks a lot , i will look at this  method. But now that you say that is an easier way, im curious .. I first thought to add physics in the wall because of the colisions , but if i can do in another (and shorter) way, hell yeah! Please , can you give me an example of how would you approuch this problem?

Comment: @Whirlwind     . . . . . . .. . . .

Comment: You haven't answered about walls dimensions ... :) Are you trying to restrict something (node eg. ball) to leave the screen or ?

Comment: @Whirlwind i was thinking to do a retangular size , about 2.3 x 4 inch =) Yes, i will put a ball (or more) inside, and this walls are going to restrict the game as well . Outside i was thinking to put simple buttons like (pause/return and exit) and score.

Comment: Okay, I will write you an example with basics. Also, don't think about inches here. Try to think in points. http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified

Comment: Wow pretty cool this paintcode!

Comment: Checkout my answer. If you have questions, feel free to ask. You can copy and paste the code to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic example of how you can restrict the ball from leaving the screen:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    let BallCategory    : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
    let WallCategory    : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2

    let ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 40)

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

      physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self



       setupWalls()

       setupBall()


    }

    func setupWalls(){


        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: frame)
        physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = WallCategory
        physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BallCategory
        physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BallCategory



    }

    func setupBall(){

        ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 40)
        ball.fillColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
        ball.name = "ball"
        ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BallCategory
        ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = WallCategory
        ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = WallCategory
        ball.physicsBody?.dynamic = true //In order to detect contact between two bodies, at least on body has to be dynamic
        ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.5


        ball.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(frame)) // placing to ball in the middle of the screen

        addChild(ball)
    }



    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {


       ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 200, dy: 200))

    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */


    }
}
```

Comment: thanks!! But about the walls, any tip to how to reduce or adjust the size of the rectangule? (maintaing the proportions of the frame). I tried this , but somehow my left and right walls are a bit out of the screen (iphone 4-7 inch)

Comment: @Yansin that is probably because of how you've initialized  your scene size. By default in SpriteKit template projects a scene is loaded from .sks file with a size of 1024x768. You can set scene size explicitly (in viewDidLoad method inside GameViewController.swift) method, like this : scene.size = skView.bounds.size.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for adding four walls with a thickness of twenty:

```
        // Create walls
    let leftWall = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: self.frame.height))
    leftWall.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    let physicsBodyLW = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 20, height: self.frame.size.height), center: CGPoint(x:10, y:self.frame.height/2))
    physicsBodyLW.affectedByGravity = false
    physicsBodyLW.dynamic = false
    leftWall.physicsBody = physicsBodyLW
    self.addChild(leftWall)

    let rightWall = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: self.frame.width - 20, y: 0, width: 20, height: self.frame.height))
    rightWall.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    let physicsBodyRW = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 20, height: self.frame.size.height), center: CGPoint(x:10, y:self.frame.height/2))
    physicsBodyRW.affectedByGravity = false
    physicsBodyRW.dynamic = false
    rightWall.physicsBody = physicsBodyRW
    self.addChild(rightWall)

    let topWall = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.height-20, width: self.frame.width, height: 20))
    topWall.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    let physicsBodyTW = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: 20), center: CGPoint(x:self.frame.width/2, y:10))
    physicsBodyTW.affectedByGravity = false
    physicsBodyTW.dynamic = false
    topWall.physicsBody = physicsBodyTW
    self.addChild(topWall)

    let bottomWall = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: 20))
    print(bottomWall.frame)
    bottomWall.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    let physicsBodyBW = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: 20), center: CGPoint(x:self.frame.width/2, y:10))
    physicsBodyBW.affectedByGravity = false
    physicsBodyBW.dynamic = false
    bottomWall.physicsBody = physicsBodyBW
    self.addChild(bottomWall)
```